# Need to fetch text from image.png in Protractor-Jasmine

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

Is there any way in Protractor-Jasmine to retrieve the text content from a png image engulfed in webpage & use the text for assert using the expect function ?

I have tried the below way but it didn't work out:

```
mypic = element(by.css("img[src*='images/logo.png']"));
    browser.isElementPresent(mypic).then(function (result) {
        if(result){
        expect((result).isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
            console.log(result.getText());
            expect(result.getText()).toEqual('Content');
        }
    });
```

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Can you share the HTML code or website ?

Comment: <a href="/ui/search">
<img src="images/logo.png" alt="Home">
</a>

Comment: You need to check whether the image is correct or not ? Is the Scenario ? Because If we Check the Image then it is obvious that text will be correct. Hope you are getting me.

Comment: yes the image is correct. if i do expect((mypic).isPresent()).toBeTruthy(); it passes correctly. so there is no problem with the image or its location as protractor is able to navigate & identify its location & presence correctly. I'm not sure that text retrieval of an image is even supported by protractor or not.

Comment: It is Supported in selenium. But i want to know what you want to verify by taking the text of an image? If image is verified then i guess that is enough for a test case for validating a image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think you need to complicate this by extracting the text content from an Image by some kind of OCR tech. You can just validate the `src,href & alt` attributes on the `img` element

```
    expect(result.getAttribute('src')).toEqual('images/logo.png');
    expect(result.getAttribute('alt')).toEqual('Home');
```

As src of a logo would be only gonna be static most of the time, this should be the simple and best way to validate